# Add folder to path, or copy symbolic links to existent directory in path?

Tags: linux, path, symbolic-link

I am running some script on a server, making use of [environment modules](http://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/Environment-Modules); basically, when I load a module for some software, it prepends the path with the folder of the software.

I am loading a lot of modules, and I have the impression that this affecting negatively the time of my script startup (`python`).

Would it be better to make symbolic links to all of the programs that I need into a folder which is already in the path, so to limit the number of folders that the OS needs to scan for finding an executable?

Is it possible to define my own module in this way, like `LINK_TO_PATH` instead of `PREPEND_PATH` ? (I didn't find anything in http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/modulefile.html)

The only problem I see is the case where more programs have the same name, am I overlooking something else?